# Why actionbar sherlock does not appear in 2.1?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I added Sherlock library to my project and I added required classes and codes to my project. When I test  it, action bar appears only in android 4 emulator. When I try it in 2.1 emulator, Actionbar does not appear. Can you give some suggestions how can I fixed it? 
I set my target 15 for both sherlock library and my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have done the following:

Set the min and target SDK levels appropriately

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Changed your `Activity`'s to `SherlockActivity`'s, and `Fragment`'s to `SherlockFragment`'s

Set your theme to either one of your own that has a parent of, or is the direct theme `Theme.Sherlock` or one of its child themes e.g. `Theme.Sherlock.Light`

Finally; the ABS styles mirror those of the native action bar therefore you need to define each style element twice. For example:

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/blue_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_gradient</item>

    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>

    <item name="icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>       

    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
</style>
```

Edit: I did a video tutorial towards getting started too: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY

Comment: I already did all of them except last one. I used Theme.Sherlock. Can you explain more last step. Where should I modify or define these styles? In my project? or sherlock library?

Comment: Hi Thanks for video. When I put SherlockAtivity instead of FragmentActivity, like in your video, my problem is solved. Thank you